# Translate using python except variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, translation, google-translate

I am trying to translate Stellaris game files to turkish language using deep translate library.

```
toBeTranslated = "Scans indicate the presence of a foreign, alien-made object on one of §H[Root.GetName]'s§! many frozen mountain tops."

translated = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='tr').translate(text=toBeTranslated)
```

Problem is that it is going to translate variables too.
Variables are in this case what is between [ and ].
Other variables can be between § and §.
So in this case I dont want string §H[Root.GetName]'s§ to be translated but everything else should be translated.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Create a regex expression to capture strings starting and ending with § or [], capture strings preceding § or [] and capture strings succeeding § or [].
2. Translate the captured preceding and succeeding strings.
3. Concatenate the translated and excluded strings.

See code below:

```
import re

regex_exp = r"([\s\S]*?)(\§.+\§|\[.+\])([\s\S]*?$)"
text = "Scans indicate the presence of a foreign, alien-made object on one of §H[Root.GetName]'s§! many frozen mountain tops."

result = re.search(regex_exp, text)

trans_group1 = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='tr').translate(text=result.group(1))
trans_group3 = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='tr').translate(text=result.group(3))

#result.group(2) is the excluded value

translated_text = trans_group1 + result.group(2) + trans_group3
```